# How do I reinitialise a Datatable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, datatable

I have a page with notifications on it which I want to refresh every 10 seconds, but I don't want to reload the entire page, just the reload the div that contains the notifications.  The notifications themselves are in a datatable, which is initialised when the page is loaded, but I've been unable to get it to reinitialise the datatable when the div is reloaded.  The div reloads fine but is then just a normal table.  Here is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    loadNotificationsTable();
});

setInterval(reloadNotificationsTable, 10000);

function reloadNotificationsTable() {
    $('#NotificationsTable').dataTable().fnDestroy();

    $("#notificationsPlaceholder").load(location.href + " #notificationsPlaceholder>*", "");

    $("#notificationsPlaceholder").ready(function () {

        loadNotificationsTable();
    });
};

function loadNotificationsTable() {
    $('#NotificationsTable').dataTable({
        ajax: "data.json",
        "bLengthChange": false,
        'iDisplayLength': 1000,
        "bSort": false,
        "bFilter": false,
        "sDom": 'ft<"bottom"ilp>',
        "bDestroy": false,
        "bPaginate": false,
        "bInfo":false
    });
};
```

Is anybody able to help me and show me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: maybe you want to reinitialize after load finishes in a callback

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try re-initializing the datatable after `load` has finished in a callback:

```
$("#notificationsPlaceholder").load(location.href + " #notificationsPlaceholder>*",function(data){
    loadNotificationsTable();
});
```

Also add this to your initialization code
since you want to replace the table

https://legacy.datatables.net/ref#bDestroy

```
"bDestroy": true,
```

Comment: Sorry, got distracted and forgot to.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to refresh the table at a regular interval of time then use this:

```
$('#table_id').DataTable().ajax.reload();
```

Use this code with setTimeout() function to refresh the datatable at a regular interval of time.